# oracle installation on windows10

Tags: database, oracle, installation, windows-10, 64-bit

### [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3JqA.png) I am trying to install oracle 12c release 2 and there is this problem with the PATH length or something(Look for the screenshot). It says:-

Environment variable: "PATH" - This test checks whether the length of the environment variable "PATH" does not exceed the recommended length. Details: 
 -

### PRVF-3919 : Failed to retrieve value of environment variable "PATH"  - Cause:  Environment variable value could not be determined.  - Action:  Check user equivalence and whether the user has administrative privileges on the node.

I have windows10 64bit. please try and explain the cause along with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check PATHs length; is it really too long? Oracle says it is, so - why should we doubt? If that's the case, make it shorter. How? Create a new environment variable, for example PATH_1 and put part of current PATH variable into it. Then append newly created variable to (a shortened) PATH, using the ";%PATH_1%".

For example:

```
- original: PATH=c:\temp;c:\my_documents\oracle\forms
- new     : PATH_1=c:\my_documents\oracle\forms
- finally : PATH=c:\temp;%PATH_1%
```